CustomH2Dialect in Hibernate 6.5
We are in the process of upgrading our project from Spring Boot 2.7 to 3.3.5, which includes an upgrade to Hibernate 6. In production, we use PostgreSQL, and for local development, we use H2.
Our existing Liquibase changelogs have column definitions like this:
<column name="change_date" type="TIMESTAMP(29) WITHOUT TIME ZONE"/>
The Problem
With Hibernate 6, I understand that there was an alignment with SQL standards, and now the maximum precision for TIMESTAMP is TIMESTAMP(9). This change is causing build errors when the application tries to validate the schema: ERROR: Specified precision exceeds the maximum precision (9)
We cannot modify old Liquibase changelogs due to versioning and backward compatibility requirements.
What I've Tried
I found that one approach is to create a custom H2 dialect that can handle this specific case. However, I was unable to adapt the code snippets I found online, which were mostly compatible with Hibernate 5.
Question
Has anyone faced a similar issue, and if so, how did you resolve it? Is there a recommended way to create a custom H2 dialect or configure Hibernate to bypass this precision problem without altering the existing Liquibase changelogs?

Who throws the error? Can you just switch of schema validation?

You can't use such column definition. Only archaic versions of H2 allow it, modern versions validate them properly. PostgreSQL supports and allows fractional seconds precision up to 6, H2 has a larger limit of 9. You need to fix this definition and add validCheckSum tag with old checksum of original incorrect changeset. There is nothing to do with Hibernate ORM here.

Warning:
The following answer only addresses how to write a CustomH2Dialect in Hibernate 6.5.
Project Tree:
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   └── com
        │       └── example
        │           ├── CustomH2Dialect.java
        │           ├── DataInitializer.java
        │           ├── DemoJpaApplication.java
        │           ├── entity
        │           │   └── Student.java
        │           └── repository
        │               └── StudentRepository.java
        └── resources
            └── application.properties

pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo-jpa</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>app</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

CustomH2Dialect.java
package com.example;

import org.hibernate.boot.model.TypeContributions;
import org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect;
import org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.spi.DialectResolutionInfo;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.internal.DdlTypeImpl;
import org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.spi.DdlTypeRegistry;

public class CustomH2Dialect extends H2Dialect {

    public CustomH2Dialect() {
        super();
    }

    public CustomH2Dialect(DialectResolutionInfo info) {
        super(info);
    }

    @Override
    protected void registerColumnTypes(TypeContributions typeContributions, ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
        super.registerColumnTypes(typeContributions, serviceRegistry);

        // Get DDL type registry
        final DdlTypeRegistry ddlTypeRegistry = typeContributions.getTypeConfiguration().getDdlTypeRegistry();

        // Register new TIMESTAMP type with precision 8
        ddlTypeRegistry.addDescriptor(new DdlTypeImpl(java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP, "timestamp(8)", this));
    }
}

DemoJpaApplication.java
default, not important
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoJpaApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoJpaApplication.class, args);
    }
}

DataInitializer.java
test, not important
package com.example;

import com.example.entity.Student;
import com.example.repository.StudentRepository;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class DataInitializer {
    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner initData(StudentRepository repository) {
        return args -> {
            Student student = new Student();
            student.setName("John Doe");
            repository.save(student);
        };
    }
}

entity/Student.java
not important.
package com.example.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Entity
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @Column(name = "create_date", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private LocalDateTime createDate;

    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        setCreateDate(LocalDateTime.now());
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getCreateDate() {
        return createDate;
    }

    public void setCreateDate(LocalDateTime createDate) {
        this.createDate = createDate;
    }
}

repository/StudentRepository.java
not important.
package com.example.repository;

import com.example.entity.Student;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {
}

application.properties
spring.application.name=demo-jpa

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
# spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=com.example.CustomH2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always

spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
# http://localhost:8080/h2-console


Run
Build
mvn clean package

Run
java -jar target/app.jar

Show: create_date timestamp(8)
HH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
Hibernate: 
    create table student (
        id bigint generated by default as identity,
        create_date timestamp(8) not null,
        name varchar(255),
        primary key (id)
    )

Note that Timestamp is shown here as Timestamp(8), which can confirm that our CustomH2Dialect function is effective.
I understand that your requirement description requires Timestamp(29).
But this answer can only answer the question of developing a CustomH2Dialect in Hibernate 6.5.
Regarding your question, it is required to set the precision of Timestamp to 29. I think the problem is not with Hibernate, but with whether the Database product itself supports it.
On the local side, it is a relatively simple method to use Docker to create a PostgreSQL Container for development.
